# Django User model foreign key failed

Tags: python, django

I am using django 2.0. For users I am using the model `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. I have stored a user with username `john` in it. I have a `Post` model which uses a User model as ForeignKey. This is my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    post_content = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField('post date')
    post_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.post_content
```

...In my `views.py` I am creating a post with:

```
from django.contrib.models import User
Post.objects.create(post_content=post_text, post_date=timezone.now(),post_user=User.objects.get(username='john'))
```

...In one part of the code. When I run I get this error:

> FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
>   IntegrityError at /

And it points to the line in which I create the user in `views.py`. 
Is there a proper way to ForeignKey a user model? Any guidance appreciated. Thank you :-).

**EDIT:It works after doing a reset to the database because I made an error with migrations. Run you migrations properly friends!**

Comment: Could you post the full traceback?

Comment: out of curiosity, did you migrate. i had a similiar issue once

Comment: use try, 
` try:
        user_temp = User.objects.get(username=userstring)
    except DoesNotExist, e:
        return None`

Comment: I had to reset my databases entirely because there was an issue with migrating... Now it works!

Comment: I faced the same error. I had changed the Meta class and didn't make the migrations. To resolve this, just make the migrations and migrate.